# Biblatex accent problem

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

So I ran into the following problem with biblatex. I use bibliography and one title's name have an accent `ó`.

Here is the entry of the `main.bib` file:

```
@misc{WikipediaSemiverseno,
author     = {},
title      = {F{\'o}rmula del semiverseno, Wikipedia},
howpublished = {\url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F{\'o}rmula_del_haversine}},
year = {(1795)}
}
```

When I try to execute `pdflatex main.tex` I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\url {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F\field {title}{F├│rmula del sem\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \field.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.204 \begin{document}

?
```

Any help will be apreciated, thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you are really using `biblatex`: (1) don't use `howpublished` to give the URL, write it into the `url` field (2) don't escape characters in the `url` field. (3) Don't use brackets in the `year` field. (Plus I doubt that 1795 is a valid date for a Wikipedia entry!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`  and is your backend `biber`?

Comment: `@misc{WikipediaSemiverseno,
  title = {Fórmula del semiverseno, Wikipedia},
  url   = {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fórmula_del_haversine},
  year  = {2017},
}` should work.

Comment: My backend is biblatex, I've got ´\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}´. Finally I used the line that @moewe write and works like a charm, thank you all for your help!

Comment: No, the backend is either `biber` (default) or `bibtex`. The advantage of biber is it understands `utf8`, so in your example you can type `fórmula` directly from your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `biblatex` you should not be using `howpublished` to give the URL, you should use the dedicated `url` field. The `url` field is special and can accept special characters that would normally have to be escaped in unescaped form

The following should work

```
@misc{WikipediaSemiverseno,
  title = {Fórmula del semiverseno, Wikipedia},
  url   = {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fórmula_del_haversine},
  year  = {2017},
}
```

but is probably still bad form.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely upon LaTeX's usual interpolation of accented characters for URLs.

You can use the [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_del_haversine), if you setup your LaTeX code for it (e.g. via `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`):  `\url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fórmula_del_haversine}`.

Alternatively, you can use the [equivalent](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%F3rmula_del_haversine) URL percent escape (UTF) encoding: `\url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%F3rmula_del_haversine}`.